# cant able to install openjdk-7-jdk and openjdk-7-jre

Tags: apt, package-management, java, openjdk, oracle

When I run

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

I am getting this error

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-7-jdk is a virtual package provided by:
  oracle-java9-installer 9b123+9b123arm-1~webupd8~0
  oracle-java8-installer 8u92+8u91arm-2~really8u91~webupd8~0
  oracle-java7-installer 7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1
You should explicitly select one to install.
E: Package 'openjdk-7-jdk' has no installation candidate


$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java-7-installer

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java-7-installer


$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-7-jdk is a virtual package provided by:
  oracle-java9-installer 9b123+9b123arm-1~webupd8~0
  oracle-java8-installer 8u92+8u91arm-2~really8u91~webupd8~0
  oracle-java7-installer 7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1
You should explicitly select one to install. 
E: Package 'openjdk-7-jdk' has no installation candidate


$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
oracle-java7-installer is already the newest version (7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 79 not upgraded.


$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-7-jdk is a virtual package provided by:
  oracle-java9-installer 9b123+9b123arm-1~webupd8~0
  oracle-java8-installer 8u92+8u91arm-2~really8u91~webupd8~0
  oracle-java7-installer 7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1
You should explicitly select one to install.
E: Package 'openjdk-7-jdk' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: if ubuntu version is 16.04 try openjdk-8-jdk

Comment: OpenJDK packages should not point to Oracle Java ones, I believe. That seems strange. Can you please [edit] your question and add the output of the command `grep -r --include '*.list' '^deb ' /etc/apt/sources.list*` to show us what software sources you have enabled?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem but I could install it after running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Comment: You may need sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys D46F45428842CE5E

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve using the following commands,

```
%sh sudo apt-get -y --allow-change-held-packages install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: this is not a answer to the question.